# Access Directory with Account and Password

Tags: python, pathlib

I am using `python lib` - `Pathlib` to access a file in the directory which requires Acc & Pwd.

Following is my current code:

```
FILE_PATH = "//192.168.10.1/Test/test.xlsx"
fileDir = pathlib.Path(FILE_PATH)
if (fileDir.exists() == False):
        print('File not found.')
```

I got this result:

```
[WinError 1326] The user name or password is incorrect: '\\\\192.168.10.1\Test\'
```

What if the login details are:

```
account: root, pwd: 123456
```

how should I revise the code so that I can access the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did is join Domain. Then there is no login  needed.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you found a solution to your problem since it's seven months old ^^.

One way of fixing your issue is to use window's credential manager to save username and password for this connection.

Now I'm looking for a way of doing this only in python without using windows' workaround. If you had any luck in doing this I'm all ears ;)

Cheers.

Comment: What I did is join the domain and there is no need to use password

Comment: Because it is really unstable when I tried to use Acc & Pwd to login and get the file